# Virtualenv - IOError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/bin/easy_install'

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pip, virtualenv

When running this command:

```
$ sudo virtualenv ENV --python=python2.7
```

I'm receiving the following:

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/bin/python2.7

New python executable in /Users/bo3423/git/My-Project/ENV/bin/python2.7
Not overwriting existing python script /Users/bo3423/git/My-Project/ENV/bin/python (you must use /Users/bo3423/git/My-Project/ENV/bin/python2.7)
Please make sure you remove any previous custom paths from your /Users/bo3423/.pydistutils.cfg file.
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
  Complete output from command /Users/bo3423/git/...ie/ENV/bin/python2.7 - setuptools pip wheel:
  The directory '/Users/bo3423/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/bo3423/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting setuptools
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8c/10/79282747f9169f21c053c562a0baa21815a8c7879be97abd930dbcf862e8/setuptools-39.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (566kB)
Collecting pip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0f/74/ecd13431bcc456ed390b44c8a6e917c1820365cbebcb6a8974d1cd045ab4/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
Collecting wheel
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/81/30/e935244ca6165187ae8be876b6316ae201b71485538ffac1d718843025a9/wheel-0.31.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (41kB)
Installing collected packages: setuptools, pip, wheel
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/req/req_set.py", line 731, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/req/req_install.py", line 841, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1040, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/wheel.py", line 476, in move_wheel_files
    generated.extend(maker.make(spec))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/distlib/scripts.py", line 353, in make
    self._make_script(entry, filenames, options=options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/distlib/scripts.py", line 257, in _make_script
    self._write_script(scriptnames, shebang, script, filenames, ext)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/distlib/scripts.py", line 231, in _write_script
    self._fileop.write_binary_file(outname, script_bytes)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/distlib/util.py", line 388, in write_binary_file
    with open(path, 'wb') as f:
IOError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/bin/easy_install'
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2327, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 711, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 944, in create_environment
    download=download,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 900, in install_wheel
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 795, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /Users/bo3423/git/...ie/ENV/bin/python2.7 - setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 2
```

I have python2.7 installed but also python3, which may be causing a conflict. I have been unsuccessful at completely uninstalling python3.

The directory and file /bin/easy_install do not exist, is there a way to configure virtualenv to point to the correct directory where easy_install is located?

I'm running this on macOS. Any help from anyone who's encountered something similar is much appreciated!

Comment: are you sure that easy_install is installed ?

Comment: Yes, when I do $ which easy_install, I get:  /usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/easy_install
But when I try to use it directly $ easy_install, I get:
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/lib/python3.6/site-packages/test-easy-install-15470.pth'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  Removed all versions of Python, virtualenv, and easy_install.  And re-installed all except for Python3.